# My 2004 F150 FX4 has a vibration in the front end

Tags: ford, f-150

My 2004 F150 FX4 has a vibration in the front end. I feel it in the accelerator pedal.  When I am driving strait or turning left it is there but to the left it stops. I have changed my cv’s and locking hubs along with the locking hub sensor. Plus the brake rotors and  had the tires Balanced and rotated no change.

Comment: Did you got your truck aligned when you changed the CV and locking hubs?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many possibilities (such as worn tie rod ends) if the vehicle has seen hard off-road use.

Bite the bullet and see a suspension expert. Correct diagnosis will save you from replacing parts that do not need to be. As you can replace C.V.s you are obviously competent. Professional diagnosis + your labour saves time and money.